# Add arrays to an array without creating a 2D array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array `word_array`, and I'd like to add all the words of sentences to it. For example:

```
word_array = []
sentence_1 = "my first sentence"
sentence_2 = "my second sentence"
```

and then have:

```
word_array = ["my", "first", "sentence", "my", "second", "sentence"]
```

If I use `split()`:

```
word_array << sentence_1.split
word_array << sentence_2.split
```

I get:

```
word_array = [["my", "first", "sentence"], ["my", "second", "sentence"]]
```

How can I avoid having a 2D array here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `concat`.

```
word_array.concat(sentence_1.split)
word_array.concat(sentence_2.split)
```

It is more efficient than using `+`, which makes a new array.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use `+=` to append the elements to the end of `word_array` every time:

```
word_array += sentence_1.split
# => ["my", "first", "sentence"]
word_array += sentence_2.split
# => ["my", "first", "sentence", "my", "second", "sentence"]
```

Comment: I get an error "no implicit conversion of String into Array"

Answer (score 3):

Just use `sentence_1.split + sentence_2.split`

I think you may confuse `+` and `<<` for array. `+` is to merge arrays, `<<` takes the argument as the array's element.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you may have more than one sentences, and you may be getting it in the form of array.  Below solution will be apt in that case, as well as if you had only couple of sentences.

```
sentence_1 = "my first sentence"
sentence_2 = "my second sentence"

ary = [sentence_1, sentence_2]
words = ary.flat_map {|s| s.split}
#=> ["my", "first", "sentence", "my", "second", "sentence"]
```

Comment: In such case, `inject` or `each_object` would be more efficient. But your answer may be conceptually simpler. And is symbol-to-proc attracting you?

Comment: @sawa - Thanks.  I was trying to avoid explicit call to `flatten` on `split` result.

Comment: I know. Using `flatten` is a bad idea in this case.